# Find mysql root password centos 7

Tags: mysql, centos, passwords

EDIT : I have finally just reset it. Thank you all.

I have installed Mysql server on Centos 7 and I can't find the temporary password.
I do : grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysqld.log
But I have not result.

Thanks.

Comment: It's probably easier to just [reset it](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html).

Answer (score 2):

If the MySql is installed properly, grep should show the result.

Please make sure :

**1) Mysql service is running :**

```
service mysqld status
```

To make sure it starts along with system start:

```
systemctl start mysqld
```

**2) Running grep with Root user**

```
sudo grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysqld.log
```

**3) /etc/my.cnf should display logging entry or similar :**

```
log = /var/log/mysqld.log
log-error = /var/log/mysqld.error.log
```